# Запуск терминала без видоядра

Tags: linux, сервер, железо, компоненты, процессор

Пытаюсь собрать максимально дешёвый сервер, столкнулся с вопросом - нужно ли видеоядро (или видеокарта) для терминала линукса?

Comment: Для терминала? Какого типа терминал? Я что-то не очень понял в чём вопрос...

Comment: RaspberryPi > 12$ полноценный сервер даже с hdmi на борту. Что вам нужно от "сервера"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать на домашнем железе, то скорее всего нужно. Многие прошивки BIOS не запустятся без видео. Самому линуксу видеоядро не нужно.